# Green pixelated numbers showing up around documents in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I got these weird green pixelated numbers changing and going around my word document... it looks like this: (this is not a joke)

[image]

**EDIT:** 
These numbers are gone after restarting Word... dun rly now why it happened.  Sorry about the trouble.

Comment: Looks like an fps counter, from some screen capture app.

Comment: Bandicam count too?

Comment: @Tetsujin, what I was going to say. Looks like Fraps.